# about check the number from string

Tags: c

This is my plan.  {i using linux(mac(xcode&terminal))}
Name of program is  Tour Company.

```
Ask for the user's first name and the discount code (3 letters plus 1 digit, e.g. "AGF2",or 0 if no discount code available).
```

---so i will use fgets to get string , How check last number , [guide #1]---

```
When the user enters a name equal to "END", you have reached the end of the day.
```

---how check input string = 'end' [guide #2]---

For each customer, repeatedly ask **date of the tour (dd/mm/yyyy), which tour, and the number of people going on the tour.** 
   Available tours are **"London" (800/person)**, **"Paris" (1000/person)**,**"Rome" (1400 baht/person)** and **"Moscow" (2500 baht/person)**. 
If the user has a discount code, take **15% off the total price if there are 1-4 people** on a tour, **20% for 5 or more people**. ---check from #1 so i will use 2 function---

When the customer enters a date beginning with **"00"**, print an invoice showing the customer name plus information about each booked tour: **date, tour name, number of people, total price before discount, discount amount, total price after discount.**
*The invoice should also show the total price for this customer.* 
---how to check have 00 before date? [guide#3]---

[from #2]At the end of the day, **print a summary showing the number of customers who had discount codes, number of customers without discount codes, the total money received for each of the four tour types before discounts, the total discounts for each tour type, and the
overall total money received.**---I not have problem about this ---

***I'm newbie of C programing*** 
---I want to make this programs **without using pointers**---
Thanks for help.
Ps.I'm weak about using english, sorry about grammar & meaning.

Comment: "I want to make this programs without using pointers" - how cute.

Comment: choose one question and ask it, showing what you've done so far. If you are looking for someone to do your homework, you will have to hire them on another site :-)

Comment: This is my friend assignment but my assignment have finished (I write atm program) i need to do this for my experience :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strcmp()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) or [strncmp()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) ,to compare input with "end"

```
fgets(input,MAX_SIZE,stdin);
if(strncmp(input,"end",3)==0)
{
//you have reached the end of the day
}
```

Comment: You are welcome... One thing Ask question with some code rather than lot of description.